# Positive/Negative lookahead with grep and perl

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep, regex-lookarounds

My login.txt file contains the following entries:

```
abc def
abc 123
def abc
abc de
tha ewe
```

When I do a positive lookahead using perl, I get the following result:

```
> cat login.txt | perl -ne 'print if /(?)abc\s(?=def)/'
abc def
```

...when I use grep, I get the following result:

```
> cat login.txt | grep -P '(?<=abc)\s(?=def)'
abc def
```

Negative lookahed results as follows from perl...:

```
> cat login | perl -ne 'print if /(?)abc\s(?!def)/'
abc 123
def abc
abc de
```

...and the grep result:

```
> cat login.txt | grep -P '(?<=abc)\s(?!def)'
abc 123
abc de
```

perl matched the `def abc` for the negative lookahead. but it shouldn't have matched `def abc`, as I'm checking `abc` then `def` pattern; whereas grep returns the correct result.

Is something missing in my perl pattern?

Comment: `(?)abc` is not a positive lookahead regex at all; you wanted `(?=)abc`. Reread the doc more closely, I'll admit it's an incredibly dense read and is best learned while experimenting...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

grep does not include the newline in the string it checks against the regex, so `abc\s` does not match when abc is at the end of the line.  chomp in perl or use the -l command line option and you will see similar results.

I'm not sure why you were making other changes between the perl and grep regexes; what was the `(?)` supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

I would try anchoring your regex like so:

```
/(^abc\s+(?!def).+)/
```

This would capture:

```
abc 123
abc de
```

The `(?)` at the beginning of your negative lookahead regex is redundant

Answer (score 2):

In your `perl -ne 'print if /(?)abc\s(?!def)/'` you asking perl to find `abc`, then space, then string shouldn't be `def`. This is successfully matches with `def abc`, because there is no `def` after `abc` here and `\s` matches with newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?)abc\s(?!def)/'
```

To begin, as fugi stated, the `(?)` is an empty non-capturing group, and matches anything, so it does nothing.

Therefore as written, this regex matches the literal string `abc` followed by a single `[:space:OR:tab:OR:newline]`, *not* followed by the literal string `def`.

Because `\s` matches a newline character and you did not chomp the trailing newline characters as you processed each line, `def abc` matches because `(?)abc\s` in the regex matches `abc[:newline:]` which is followed by `$` (the end-of-line anchor, *not* `def`).

The corrected regex (accounting for the redundant `(?)`) would be:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<=abc)\s(?!def)/'
```

...which matches a single `[:space:OR:tab:OR:newline]` which is preceded by `abc` and *not* followed by `def`.

This *still* will match `def abc`, because once again, `\s` matches the `[:newline:]`, which is preceded by `abc` and followed by `$` (the end-of-line anchor, not `def`).

Either chomp the `[:newline:]` before evaluating the regex in Perl, or use the character class [ \t] (if you need to account for tab characters) instead of `\s`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<=abc)[ \t](?!def)/'
```

Or simply

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<=abc) (?!def)/'
```

Comment: `(?)` is NOT an empty non-capturing group, it's a nonsense, an error.