# Create string array from git status bash output

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to create a string array of my modified git files so I can use them in a bash program. Sample output:

```
On branch restructured
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/restructured'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified: path/to/file1 
    modified: path/to/file2
```

I'm tryig to grab the text after `modified:` but from what I've found grep doesn't [support new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656914/positive-negative-lookahead-with-grep-and-perl#20657574) so i'm at a loss how I could convert the raw output into something I could work with.

Comment: I would suggest starting with `git status --porcelain`, which is specifically geared towards being easy(-er) to parse...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

`files=(git status | grep '^\s*modified:' | cut -f 2- -d :)`

Reading from inside out, that:

- Passes `git` status to `grep`, which
- looks for lines with `modified:` on them singularly, then
- cuts everything after the colon on those lines, then finally
- puts that into an array assigned to `$files`

Comment: How about files=$(git ls-files -m)

Answer (score 8):

If you really just want a list of modified files, consider [`git ls-files -m`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html). If you need something extensible to potentially other types of changes:

```
git status --porcelain | while read -r status file; do
  case "$status" in 
    M) printf '%s\n' "$file";;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the problem wrong.

Git "status" is a pretty view derived from a number of underlying commands.

The list of "changed" files is retrieved with

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M
modifiedfile.txt
```

diff-filter can be:

- A Added files
- C Copied files
- D Deleted files
- M Modified files
- etc.. check the manual.

You can also try **ls-files** which supports -d, -m, -a, and -o.

If you are looking for NEW files which are not yet tracked, you can try

```
$ git ls-files -o
untrackedfile.txt
```

As a last resort, if you really insist on trying to parse the output from git-status, consider using the '--short' or '--porcelain' output option.  --short produces coloured output, which --porcelain avoids.

```
$ git status --short
 M modifiedfile.txt
?? untrackedfile.txt
```